# How does onWhy is $\int\phi=0$ for $\phi\in\mathcal{D}$ for $\phi$ with co´nvex support equivalent to $\phi=\sum \partial_j F_j$?

Tags: functional-analysis

How does one prove $\int\phi=0$ for $\phi\in\mathcal{D}$ for $\phi$ with convex support is equivalent to $\phi=\sum \partial_j F_j$ ?

I actually, don't quite see why convex support is explicitly mentioned here and how it factors into a proof.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and nice formatting. It would be helpful if you were a bit more explicit with everything. What is $\mathcal{D}$, for example?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincare_lemma